# bash: how to see real time output from spawned script

Tags: bash, process, stdout, spawning

Consider the following scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
# fee.sh
echo "fee"

#!/bin/bash
# foo.sh
echo "foo"
./fee.sh &
```

Now execute the foo script.

```
$ ./foo.sh
foo
```

Only the output from foo.sh is visible.
The output from fee.sh, which is spawned within foo.sh, is not visible.

Comment: Does your `foo.sh` script only contains these lines? You didn't play with `exec` in your terminal don't you?

Comment: Yes. All I want is to see the output from the "echo" in real time, not after the spawned process has executed.

Comment: Well, spawned processes will write to the terminal in real time by default, so I couldn't reproduce the issue with your example.

Comment: Interesting. I cannot see any real time output from the spawned process. I don't see any output until the process ends. Even then the screen doesn't do anything until I press RETURN. Then I finally get the output and the status returned by the spawned process.

Comment: Maybe your unspecified process, which is more complex than shown, is suffering from buffering.

Comment: Ah. Wait. My problem is that I am trying to get the output of a subprocess of a process.
So, I have edited my original post to correctly reflect that.

Comment: No problem, I get `foo` `fee` with bash 3 & 4. You must something muting the output in your script.

Comment: When I execute './foo.sh', I only see "foo", I don't see "fee".

Comment: First you say "The output from fee.sh… is not visible", then you say "I finally get the output". Don't make contradictory or incomplete statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

```
set -b
sleep 3 &
```

Check out `help set`.

Comment: Well, no, that won't do.
I'm actually doing something more complex than just "echo foo". I just used that as an example. 
What I want is to get real time output from a spawned process, rather than waiting for it to end and just getting a status or tailing a log file.

Comment: What do you feel is the difference between *"real time output"* and tailing a log file please?

Comment: "real time output" appears on the screen as the process is executing.
Tailing a log file means that the user must do ...
```
$ tail /var/log/messages
```
... in order to see output from the process.